# Install psycopg2 on Synology

Tags: python-2.7, synology

I try to install psycopg2 on my DS2413+ (DSM 4.3). I've installed Python 2.7 with ipkg and pip. When I do :

```
/opt/local/bin/pip2.7 install psycopg2
```

I got the following error :
Error: pg_config executable not found.

```
Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
or specify the full executable path with the option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
running egg_info
```

But I didn't found `pg_config` in my `/usr/syno/` where a built in version of `pgsql` is already installed. 
In other topics with this kind of error, they recommend to install `python-dev`, but I can't manage to install it on my NAS ... There is also a `py26-psycopg2` ikpg but I need to install it on Python 2.7.

If anyone has a solution to these problem please tell me :')

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install psycopg2, it is already installed in the site-packages if you used the official Synology python package, see

```
/usr/local/packages/@appstore/Python/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Also, using pip from ipkg may mess up your python install as there should really be one python2.7 installation.